# Extract individual values from array on Xcode queried from Parse

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm querying some values from parse that go into an array called "users" through a for in loop. Once the values are in the array, I want to extract individual value and parts within the array index. However, I'm having trouble doing this. Here is my code:

```
  var query = PFQuery(className:"UserData")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objectss {

            var topUsers:PFObject = object as PFObject

            self.users.append("\(object)")


        }

        println(self.users[2])
```

the output I get to the consol is :

```
 <UserData: 0x7fa5a848f570, objectId: RlvK3GhfqE, localId: (null)> {
 hot = 59;
 imageNumber = 1;
 not = 17;
 totalVotes = 104;
 }
 <UserData: 0x7fa5a85cfdc0, objectId: 30WlVtgurP, localId: (null)> {
 hot = 13;
 imageNumber = 2;
 not = 24;
 totalVotes = 37;
 }
 <UserData: 0x7fa5a85d02f0, objectId: 5D6ARjk3xS, localId: (null)> {
 hot = 7;
 imageNumber = 3;
 not = 23;
 totalVotes = 31;
 }
 <UserData: 0x7fa5a85d02f0, objectId: 5D6ARjk3xS, localId: (null)> {
 hot = 7;
 imageNumber = 3;
 not = 23;
 totalVotes = 31;
 }
```

How can I extract: "hot" and the number value on it's own? or "not" or "totalVotes"?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the attributes, but reference the name of it. You should check for array length and null values, but in general:

```
self.users[2]["hot"]
```

Also, in your find block, you should be able to just set your `users` array directly, without iterating through all of the objects.

```
self.users = objects
```

Comment: println(self.users[2]["hot"]) gives me an error: "Missing argument for parameter #2 in call." Nor can I do println(self.users["hot"]) it gives me the same error... thanks

Comment: Ultimately, the main goal is to print each individual value from an index in the array to labels on the UI. And as the UI button is triggered to see the next image for the next array value, I would just increment which array index value is being shown.